# TYPO3 v11: PHP Warning: Undefined array key "cleverreach"

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I'm getting an error every time I submit a form.

I've updated my TYPO3 installation from v10 to v11. Everything was fine. The only problem I have is when I try to use the websites contact form: The message is send, but I can't get the redirect page. Instead i get the error below:

> "PHP Warning: Undefined array key "cleverreach" in /home/www/[...]/typo3conf/ext/cleverreach/Classes/Powermail/Finisher/CleverReach.php line 68"

More infos:

- TYPO3: 11.5.24
- Webserver Apache
- PHP Version: 8.1.16
- DB: MySQL 10.5.15

Comment: It seems you found the solution yourself: https://github.com/WapplerSystems/cleverreach/issues/50

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `cleverreach` extension isn't compatible with PHP 8.1. In PHP < 8.1 undefined array key was a notice and usually not displayed as error (depending on your PHP/TYPO3 configuration). Since PHP 8.1 it's a warning and is usually displayed as an error.

I'm not familiar with the extension, but this warning can usually be easily fixed. For example `$myVariable = $myArray['undefinedKey'];` can be changed to `$myVariable = $myArray['undefinedKey'] ?? 'defaultValue';`. Though there might also be other errors that need to be fixed, as they've apparently not tested the extension with PHP 8.1.

You can fix this by either:

- Contact the authors of the extension and ask them to fix it.
- Fix the warning in the extension yourself.
- Change your PHP/TYPO3 configuration to not display PHP warnings.
- Downgrade your PHP version to 8.0.